# run escpos module with electron

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, escpos

I'm  working on electron project, I'm facing problem when trying to use "escpos" module, it shows me this error:

```
    Uncaught Error: The module '/Users/Fateh/Desktop/electron-test/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build/Release/bindings.node'`enter code here
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 73. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:138)
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:138)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:828)
    at Object.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:138)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:138)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16)
    at bindings (/Users/Fateh/Desktop/electron-test/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112)`
```

Knowing that I'm using node JS v11.6.0, Electron v6.0.12 and escpos v 2.5.2

apprently escpos is built under node 8 version , 
is there a way to run it under node js 11 ?